# Someone's inheriting a castle: 'Castle heirs', 'Heirs of the Castle', or 'Heirs to the Castle'?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, attributive-nouns

What is the correct way to describe people inheriting a castle? (American and British English)

> Castle heirs

or

> Heirs *of* the castle

or

> Heirs *to* the castle

It's just a phrase I've heard, but I've seen it written in various ways and I want to know which is the correct way.
"heirs to the kingdom, heirs to the castle, heirs to blah blah". Sometimes they put, example, "heirs of the crown" or "crown heirs".

Comment: Heirs to the castle is what I'd say.

Comment: Compare 'heir to the throne' vs 'throne heir' in Google searches.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth My question is a plural sentence, not singular

Comment: Because "heir" sounds like the more common word "air", you should try and find a phrase that can't be mistaken for something about "air". "Air of the castle" and "castle air" are valid, "Air to the castle" doesn't make much sense. This writing advice is off-topic, so take it before it's deleted;)

Comment: Compare 'heirs to the throne' vs 'throne heirs' in Google searches. Mirrored ratios.

Comment: As @Greybird says "heirs to the castle" (something) and "heirs of a lord" (someone).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean heir or inheritor?
heirs are listed in wills and are supposed to inherit the loot,
**becoming *the inheritors of the castle OR castle inheritors.*** The same goes for heir: the castle heirs or heirs of the castle.

heirs to the castle is possible but would not be used in a legal text. It is more literary. No, I cannot prove it. [:)] Heir to a great fortune.

Just like: **the owner of the car, the car owner**. In English, we often use a noun as an adjective, AKA an attributive noun.

[attributive nouns](https://English%20often%20uses%20nouns%20as%20adjectives%20-%20to%20modify%20other%20nouns.%20For%20example,%20a%20car%20that%20people%20drive%20in%20races%20is%20a%20race%20car.%20A%20car%20with%20extra%20power%20or%20speed%20is%20a%20sports%20car.%20Nouns%20that%20modify%20other%20nouns%20are%20called%20adjectival%20nouns%20or%20noun%20modifiers.%20For%20our%20purposes,%20they%20are%20called%20attributive%20nouns.%20So%20we%20will%20use%20that%20term.)

> [heir and inheritor from this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/532472/whats-the-difference-between-the-words-heir-heritor-and-inheritor)

Comment: heir to anything It can be a castle, or a kingdom. What I want to know is how the sentence is structured

Comment: @acgbox What sentence? This is a phrase.  I have answered your question, why are you reposing it again now? I just don't get why people do this. Sure, kingdom, castle, pile of money and a lot of other stuff one can imagine, can be inherited.

Comment: One is an heir *of* a person, and an heir *to* an item or title. An "heir of the castle" would be a descendent of the castle itself, which makes no sense. Charles was the heir *of* (not *to*) Elizabeth, and was the heir *to* the throne, not the heir *of* the throne.

Comment: It's just a phrase I've heard, but I've seen it written in various ways and I want to know which is the correct way. "heirs to the kingdom, heirs to the castle, heirs to blah blah". Sometimes they put, example, "heirs of the crown" or "crown heirs".

Comment: I don't know who qualified your answer as negative. I don't think it's bad. I'll give you a point for effort

Comment: @NuclearHoagie You are completely mistaken: Heir of the manor or castle is perfectly fine English. The heirs of the castle put forward only one condition. https://www.orangesmile.com/extreme/en/forgotten-buildings/boldt-castle.htm

Comment: Title: The Heir of the Manor, or the Spoiled Child of Fortune Artist: After (?) John George Landseer (British, 1763/69–1852 London), Metropolitan Museum

Comment: @Lambie I'll admit Google ngrams did surprise me with how common it is, but "heir to the castle/manor" is still several times more common than "heir of the castle/manor". For other item/title phrases the skew is much worse, "heir of the throne" is virtually unheard of compared to "heir to the throne", same with "fortune" and "estate".

Comment: @NuclearHoagie You may be right, but still the content of the link doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie How common something is, is not the question. The question is about the possibility of saying a or b.

Comment: I remind you that my question is about plural phrases, not singular. I don't know if there will be a difference, but it is good to clarify it

Comment: @acgbox The point is that if a noun is used an an adjective, it has to be singular...

Comment: No. My question is plural. Not singular. So if my question is wrong, someone propose in the answer the correction in plural, not singular

Comment: @acgbox There is nothing wrong with your question. But you are not reading me properly: The **heirs** [PLURAL] of the castle or to the castle can be expressed as the **castle heirs**. A noun (castle) used as an **adjective** is always in the singular.

Comment: @Lambie thank you. Clarified the doubt. So, I can conclude, according to your answer, that all forms of the expression, described in my question, are correct. If this is correct, post your full answer

Comment: @acgbox I already **have**. castle heirs, heirs of the castle, heirs to the castle. They are all there.

Comment: @Lambie yes. you are right. sorry

Answer (score 0):

One is generally an heir *of* a person, but an heir *to* an item or title. If you inherit a castle from your father, you are the heir *of* your father, and the heir *to* the castle.

This convention is quite strict for certain things, for example, one would never describe an "heir of the throne", only an "heir to the throne". It's perhaps a bit looser for other things, so it may not be totally unheard of to describe an "heir of the castle", but "heir to the castle" is the far more common usage.

Comment: In legal language, it's heirs of an estate (as in wills and estate). Anyway: In the same year, Elizabeth Hansard, the existing heir of the castle, was married to Sir Francis Ayscough. https://castrumtocastle.com/english-castles/darlington-walworth-castle/

Comment: 'Castle heirs' sound like a bunch of heirs-in-waiting waiting in a castle.